# Trying to figure out how to create links using createTextNode

Tags: javascript, html, javafx, webview, javafx-11

First off I would like to say, the person that originally created this portion of the code is no longer on the team.

We are creating a development tool to Administrate and Develop servers for our game, that has its own programming language.

I'm using JavaFX with WebView to generate the chat area of the development tool to communicate with other developers and staff. However I want it so hen you post a link it actually shows as a link instead of plain text. I have tried things such as AutoLinker with no success. Here is the HTML portion of the webview.

```
<script src=".././scripts/Autolinker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  app = null;
  const messages = document.getElementById("messages");

  function addMessage(message, options) {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    const c = message.indexOf(":");
    const modifiedMessage = message; //replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(message);
    const ridBrackets = options.replace(/[\[\]']/g, "");
    const tokenize = ridBrackets.split(",", 2);
    const rcChatOptions = tokenize;
    const mFontColor = tokenize[rcChatOptions.BFONTCOLOR];
    let timeStampFormat = tokenize[rcChatOptions.TIMESTAMP];
    if(c > -1) {
      const u = document.createElement("span");
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      u.className = "user";
      if(mFontColor != null) {
        u.style.color = mFontColor;
      } else {
        u.style.color = "#00c02b";
      }
      //Turn plain text links into actual links
      u.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Autolinker.link(modifiedMessage.substring(0, c + 1))));
      p.appendChild(u);
      if(document.selectedfont != null) {
        p.style.fontFamily = document.selectedfont;
      }
      p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(modifiedMessage.substring(c + 1)));
    } else {
      p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(modifiedMessage));
    }
    // Append message and scroll to bottom (if at bottom)
    const scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    const scrolledToBottom = scrollTop + window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight;
    if(scrolledToBottom) {
      messages.appendChild(p);
      window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft, document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
    } else {
      messages.appendChild(p);
    }
    messages.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
  
</script>
```

I removed portions of the code that I felt was just a distraction.

This what the tool looks like

https://share.getcloudapp.com/kpuNDB4m

this is what it looks like using AutoLinker

https://share.getcloudapp.com/8LunomDL

(So auto linker is doing its job, it just still isn't rending as HyperLinks)

Comment: DOM TextNodes only accept text. So the issue is not with Autolinker, it is that fact that you are dealing with text only DOM Nodes. You need to create `<a>` tags and place the url into the `href` attribute of an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the TextNode is created after collecting some substring which would be the link. Here's an example of what it would look like if a link was created directly in js then passed to the TextNode.
One thing you can do is place the text inside of an a tag within a paragraph and then convert like so:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.innerHTML = 'Website: <a href="http://somelink.com" </a>
link.href = 'http://somelink.com';
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('http://somelink.com'));
```

Comment: Although this leads me i the right direction, how would I do something a little bit more complicated. Lets say my text was "Carlito: random text www.test.com some more random test www.test2.com (with multiple links within a sentence)

Answer (score 0):

After getting pointed in the right direction (By Frank, Thank You) I found a javascript Library that helped me accomplish what I was looking for.

Library

https://github.com/cferdinandi/saferInnerHTML

Here is an example!

https://share.getcloudapp.com/nOuDPnlp

Usage:

```
saferInnerHTML(message, modifiedMessage, true);
```

The last param is an option, append or overwrite.

Obviously, I will have to do some CSS work to make them not display as buttons. But it is exactly what I was trying to achieve.